# Quake Terminal: Switch to numbered tab

Tags: shortcut-keys, guake

Is there a way to directly navigate to a tab in guake instead of cycling?

In most tabbed apps I can press ALT+1 to go to the first terminal, ALT+2 for the second, etc.  Guake seems to only let me cycle between tabs (CTRL+Page Down).

I don't want to use yakuake.  I'm also aware of tilda but it's a little quirky.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the tabs are numbered 1-10.

Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Fn gets you to the nth tab.

So, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> gets you to the first tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> gets you to the second tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> gets you to the third tab, and so on.